# Why doesn't super().__class__.__name__ return the name of my base class?

Tags: python-3.x, super, superclass, introspection

I have a base class `A` that I inherit from to create class `B`.  If I call the name dunder on the class instance, I get the name of the class.  if I call the name dunder on the instance's base class, I get the name of the base class.  This makes sense so far.  However, if call the name dunder on the instance' super(), I don't get the name of the base class and I'm not sure why.  To make matters more confusing, If I call the name dunder on the supers()'s base class, I get the correct name for the base's base class `object`.

```
class A:
    pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.inherited_class_name = self.__class__.__name__
        self.base_class_name = self.__class__.__bases__[0].__name__
        self.should_return_base_class_name = super().__class__.__name__
        self.base_class_base_class = super().__class__.__bases__[0].__name__


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    print(b.inherited_class_name)
    print(b.base_class_name)
    print(b.should_return_base_class_name)  # Why does this return "super" instead of "A"?
    print(b.base_class_base_class)  # Especially when this one works...
```

prints out

```
B
A
super 
object
```

I don't understand why "super" is returned from my `should_return_base_class_name` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because super is in fact a distinct class that abstracts away your base class. Super is not actually the base class. When you do `super()` you are getting an instance of the super class, not an instance of your base class.
If you try `print(super())` in your example you will get `<super: <class 'B'>, <B object>>`

Answer (score 3):

`super()` returns a `super` object. If you ask Python for the `__name__` of the `__class__` of a `super` object, it's going to tell you that that name is `super`.

See the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=super#super): `super()` returns a proxy object, not an object of the base class as you (I assume) expect.

The fact that you need to access super's `__class__` should hint at that, as, if `super()` returned the base class itself, it would already be a class, and it can't return an instance of it, because there's no indication of which instance that would be.